# Which version of Micro Cloud Foundry works with cf?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I installed the recommended version of Micro Cloud Foundry (v119) and when trying to set it as target in cf, I get the error message: "V1 targets are no longer supported."

The latest version of Micro Cloud Foundry I could find is v123. Will it work as target in cf?

Comment: OK, so tried to set a running Micro Cloud Foundry v123 as target in cf and the same error message appears.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the vmc gem not cf with Micro Cloud Foundry. The cf gem is for version 2 only.